# SignalR blocks chrome UI?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, signalr

I'm having a problem with SignalR and so far can not understand why.
I've wrote a hub for long order processing operation and noticed, that it updates progress ok within FireFox, but has a problem with Chrome.
So, I've wrote simple test hub to check what is going on:

```
public class SimpleHub: Hub
{
    public void LongProcess()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);            
        Clients.Caller.AddProgress("Step 1 of 5 has completed.");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Clients.Caller.AddProgress("Step 2 of 5 has completed.");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Clients.Caller.AddProgress("Step 3  of 5 has completed.");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Clients.Caller.AddProgress("Step 4 of 5 has completed.");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Clients.Caller.AddProgress("Step 5 of 5 has completed.", true);
    }
}
```

What it does, it adds progress every several seconds. It works as supposed in clean project in both browsers - every couple seconds appears new progress message in browser.
But when I try it on real project, with Firefox it works ok, but in Chrome it looks like it completely blocks UI(doesn't even repaint Chrome console) and only when LongProcess finishes, it adds all progress messages.
So question is, what could be cause of this - may be some jQuery setting? Any ideas what to check?
Btw, I've tried `longPolling` and `serverSendEvents` (this was chosen auto by signalR in Chrome), same result on both.

Update: added client code:

```
var hub = $.connection.SimpleHub;

hub.client.AddProgress = function (progress) {
   $("#placeOrderProgress").append('<li><span>' + progress + '</span><i></i></li>');
};              

$.connection.hub
            .start()
            .done(function () {                    
                      hub.server.longProcess($('#checkoutForm').toJSON());
                 });
```

Comment: what is you client code?

Comment: updated question with client code.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the server and when you initiate the connection via Chrome ensure that your server side method triggers.  Usually hanging occurs from not being able to instantiate the connection.

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen - well, I could try that tomorrow, but that would not explain why I get results in the end, as written in question.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see that you eventually had it return values.  What transport's are being used in Firefox?  It should be the same as Chrome and in some cases even WebSockets (based on browser/server support).

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen - good question, I'll check that and will give you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.
We had in couple places where jQuery remote validation is used this piece of code (to avoid racing conditions):

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async : false });
```

So when I removed it, SignalR started working fine on Chrome. Interestingly enough, on FireFox it does not have any influence - it works with or without this line of code.